# ISP lite заглушка

Tags: debian

Добрый день.
При создании домена ИСП сразу загружает в него индекс заглушку, папку австатс

Где находится этот самый фаил заглушка. Хотелось бы указать свои файлы которые надо загружать, чтобы при добавлении доменов вместо стандартного Welcome было мое сообщение с логотипом.

OS debian
ISP установлен тут: /usr/local/ispmgr/
Вот тут : /usr/local/ispmgr/www/disabled Лежит индексный фаил при отключенном сайт (сайт отключен администратором)
Сервер ВПС

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `/usr/local/ispmgr/etc/www.skel`

Вот тут. Нашел.